# Can FireFox be Installed with a Fixed Set of Extensions that cannot be Changed by End-Users?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

There is a way to bundle FireFox with a fixed list of extensions and that users won't be able to install/uninstall them after ?
A big company with lots of IE6 search a way to do that, they'are afraid about extensions and security if users can install anything.

Comment: They can't migrate IE6. They made big strategic mistakes because they have business applications linked with IE6 ...

Comment: I think what Ricket means is that this question belongs to www.superuser.com and not Stackoverflow.

Comment: oh, i see ! thx ... (i'm not english people, sorry)

Comment: I find putting "with lots of IE6" and "afraid about ... security" in the same sentence a bit amusing.

Comment: Yes fun, isn't it ! :) Since further years i'am asking us to leave from ie6, an award wining security holes browser ... I show them all the actual posts and news around ie6 but nothings help moving ... Incredible ! So, if I can propose a solution that satisfy their needs, this will kill about 8 thousands ie6 ... and that sounds good ...

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of potential options for this, some, however, will depend upon your environment. if you have A Windows domain, for example, you could look as applications such as:

[Firefox ADM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firefoxadm)
or
[WetDog](http://wetdog.sourceforge.net/)

Another option is:

[Public Fox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3911/)

A good place to start would be:

[Firefox :2.0 Institutional Deployment - MozillaWiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox:2.0_Institutional_Deployment)
and
[Firefox:Corporate Deployment Guide](http://varun21.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Thx a lot for answer ! I will have a look to all your links.
(And yes, Windows domain)

Answer (score 1):

You can install extensions globally, using the following command line:

`path\to\firefox\firefox.exe -install-global-extension path\to\extension\file.xpi`

This will insall the addon for all users. Users will be able to *disable* the addon, but cannot *uninstall* it.

It is also possible to customize the installer to change the default user profile, and to lock machine-wide settings. Basically anything which can be configured in `about:config` can be configured that way. Google around for "customized firefox install". I can post some links later if you have trouble with it.

Comment: Beat me to it by just a couple of minutes. Users will still be able to run Firefox in "safe mode" with no addons loaded at all.

Comment: Yep, they will. I believe locked settings will still apply, but addons will be disabled. I am unaware of any way to disable safe mode for a particular user, but there may be. You could certainly delete the link to it - that would prevent 90% from getting into safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is an addon that does that:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3911/

Comment: Already saw it. The problem with this one is that the user can bypass the addon password by restarting FF in safe-mode then modify password and free to customise his FF ...
(see : developer comments)
Need something that user cannot bypass, easily ...
Thx for your answser.